# How to use requests_mock to ensure the right session is being invoked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-requests

I have a situation that is similar to this:

```
import unittest
import requests_mock
import requests

import mock

class ClassUnderTest:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.foo_url = 'http://google.com'

    def do_foo(self):
        return self.session.get(self.foo_url)

    def do_foo_failing(self):
        # I want to prevent accidentally doing this sort of operation
        # instead of reusuing self.session
        return requests.get(self.foo_url)
```

I want to make sure that the methods perform correctly, but also ensure I am using the `self.session` object. In practice I have encountered this issue because I errantly added a `requests.get` call instead of re-usuing the same session.

However this means tests like this do not actually test this functionality:

```
class TestClassUnderTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @requests_mock.mock()
    def test_do_foo_should_pass(self, m):
        c = ClassUnderTest()

        m.get('http://google.com', status_code=200)
        r = c.do_foo()

        self.assertEqual(200, r.status_code)
        self.assertEqual(m.call_count, 1)

    @requests_mock.mock()
    def test_do_foo_should_fail(self, m):
        c = ClassUnderTest()
        m.get('http://google.com', status_code=200)
        r = c.do_foo_failing()

        self.assertEqual(200, r.status_code)
        self.assertEqual(m.call_count, 1)
```

I have thought about replacing `self.session` with a mock, but then I also have to do things like set status_code on the mock (and in my real code example I also need to do things like add a mock [`.json()` method](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) so that the code consuming the response functions correctly).

Is there a way using requests_mock to effectively guarantee that only `self.session` is being used (and not `requests.get` in this example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works by wrapping all of the `request.Session` functions to a MockClass, with a wrapper that tracks usage of them:

```
class MockSession:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self._called_methods = {}

        def session_decorator(f):
            def func(*args, **kwargs):
                if f.__name__ not in self._called_methods:
                    self._called_methods[f.__name__] = 1
                else:
                    self._called_methods[f.__name__] += 1
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            return func

        for name, f in inspect.getmembers(self.session):
            if inspect.ismethod(f):
            setattr(self, name, session_decorator(f))
```

After using this mock you can access the `._called_methods` value to check how often individual methods are called. Note because of how requests_mock works you must do this at runtime (rather than loadtime by simply extending the requests.Session class with similar functionality).

Modifying the test code results in:

```
class TestClassUnderTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @requests_mock.mock()
    def test_do_foo_should_pass(self, m):
        c = ClassUnderTest()
        c.session = MockSession()
        m.get('http://google.com', status_code=200)
        r = c.do_foo()

        self.assertEqual(200, r.status_code)
        self.assertEqual(m.call_count, 1)
        self.assertEqual(c.session._called_count['GET'], 1)

    @requests_mock.mock()
    def test_do_foo_should_fail(self, m):
        c = ClassUnderTest()
        c.session = MockSession()
        m.get('http://google.com', status_code=200)
        r = c.do_foo_failing()

        self.assertEqual(200, r.status_code)
        self.assertEqual(m.call_count, 1) 

        # This will fail with an attribute error 
        # because that function was never invoked on the mock session
        self.assertEqual(c.session._called_count['GET'], 1)
```